# how do i paste and assign string to javascript variable, if string is weird?

Tags: javascript

This string is url part that comes after `http://www.domain.com/?----this-part----`.

but my string is huge and it has quotes every now and then, single and double. etc.

Edit: originally i thought the quotes were messing it up but now it seems i was wrong. So i'm pasting whole string.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/21d40cabfc5252d1a7dd

Comment: You need to escape it for javascript...

Comment: You need to give at least an example of the string you're trying to paste

Comment: Are you wanting to escape those quotes? if so you do so like this
`"he said, \"Hello there!\""`
a slash \ is javascripts escape character to ignore the following character and read it as a string.

Comment: how do i it for whole page, not manually right?

Comment: i could see myself doing it in javascript if i just could get into a variable

Comment: If I well understand, from your edit we know that there is no problem with quotes. But now what exactly is the problem? In other words, how is your string "weird" and which error does it cause (or what can't you do)?

Comment: right. even though string is big but when i assign it i get like 25% of it in variable. Try in chrome console

Answer (score 2):

If the string is delimited by `"` You can replace `"` with `\"`

If the string is delimited by `'` you can replace `'` with `\'`

As an example:

```
var str = 'It\'s me';  // Is a string with the text It's me
```

If you take the string from the code is already a string so you don't need any modification.

If you take the string from a copy from the browser url you can past it in  an editor (notepad, ultraedit, vi, vim, leafpad...) and use the function *"Replace"*

Comment: yes only my string is 1 page long, is there more automatic way to do it

Comment: please take a look at question again, i added the string